# Find the key points of the outer layer of n overlapping rectangles - Divide and Conquer

Tags: algorithm, sorting, divide-and-conquer

Given a set of *n* rectangles depicted as: *[Li, Ri, Hi]* whereby the corners of the *i-th* rectangle are - *(Li, 0), (Ri,0), (Li, Hi)* and *(Ri, Hi)*.

The goal is to print all of the **key points** of the outer layer of the n overlapping rectangles (given in a list).

**Key points** (Xj, Yj) are the points that collectively portray the outer layer of the rectangles - look at the example below:

Given the two blocks [4, 13, 4] and [2, 7, 10] the **output** should be: [2,0], [2,10],  [7,10],  [7,4], [13,4] and [13,0]  (The points that are marked red).

This should be done in O(nlogn) time where n is the number of buildings (rectangles).

[image]

I have tried to solve this problem by -

(1) Sorting the blocks by priority: Li then Ri then Hi.

(2) Compare any two blocks: [Li, Ri, Hi] and [Li+1, Ri+1, Hi+1] (15 different cases like Li==Li+1 and Hi< Hi+1 and stuff like this).

(3) Remove/add points according to condition (using AVL)

This works in some cases, but in others it fails miserably.

I am not asking for a code - a pseudo code or an explanation/algorithm would be best :)
I hope you can help me with this one!

Thank you

Comment: BTW your (n log n) budget is all spent on sorting, isn't it?

Comment: It could be both for sorting and for a recursive solution.

Comment: what is the source of the task? If it is homework or online challenge I would be reluctant to share even algorithm or pseudocode

Comment: Also, why is the title featuring Divide and conquer? Is it a firm requirement of the assignment?

Comment: Divide and Conquer is a probable solution method, it might be solved without it. This is a question from past exams.

Comment: plus a pseudocode would only be a small yet vital part of the question - I would still have to analyze time complexity, used data structures and prove why this method is correct.

Comment: Let me try to hint you just a bit in the beginning then. Sorting + stack data structure + something similar to sweeping line seems to be the correct ingredients for the task.

Comment: I tried using convex hull algorithm, after sorting the blocks, but again, I am exhausted by which conditions to check.